# Flutter: Can't Preload intial value List in MultiSelectBottomSheetField

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am using `multi_select_flutter` and trying to implement Multi Select Widget in Flutter. I want the widget to preload a list (selectedFonts). I tried using the initialValue argument but it doesn't seem to work the way I want it to. I've been trying to deal with this for quite a long time, I even tried initializing within initState and putting setState().

```
            Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                MultiSelectBottomSheetField<Font?>(
                  initialChildSize: 0.7,
                  maxChildSize: 0.8,
                  initialValue: selectedFonts,
                  listType: MultiSelectListType.CHIP,
                  checkColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 65, 78, 158),
                  selectedColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 21, 55),
                  selectedItemsTextStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  unselectedColor: Colors.greenAccent[200],
                  buttonIcon: Icon(
                    Icons.add,
                    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                  ),
                  searchHintStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 20,
                  ),
                  searchable: true,
                  buttonText: Text(
                    'FONT', //"????",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      color: Colors.grey,
                    ),
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    maxLines: 5,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    "Fonts",
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 25,
                      color: Colors.pink,
                    ),
                  ),
                  items: _items,
                  onConfirm: (values) {
                    setState(() {
                      selectedFonts = values;
                    });
                    print('selected : ${selectedFonts}');
                    selectedFonts.forEach(
                        (item) => item == null ? print('') : print(item));
                    /*senduserdata(
                    'partnerreligion', '${selectedFonts.toString()}');*/
                  },
                  chipDisplay: MultiSelectChipDisplay(
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 18,
                      color: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    onTap: (value) {
                      setState(() {
                        selectedFonts.remove(value);
                      });

                      print('removed: ${selectedFonts.toString()}');
                    },
                  ),
                ),
                selectedFonts == null || selectedFonts.isEmpty
                    ? MultiSelectChipDisplay(
                        onTap: (item) {
                          setState(() {
                            selectedFonts2.remove(item);
                            print(
                                'removed below: ${selectedFonts2.toString()}');
                          });
                          _multiSelectKey.currentState?.validate();
                        },
                      )
                    : MultiSelectChipDisplay(),
              ],
            ),
```

Comment: Are you using `multi_select_flutter`? Can you include full widget [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Yes sir, I am using multi_select_flutter. 
Here is code to reproduce the problem

```

Comment: The above code is inside the Scaffold body.
Some variables used are:

Comment: `static List<Font> fontList = [
    Font(id: 1, name: "A"),
    Font(id: 2, name: "B"),
    Font(id: 3, name: "C"),
    Font(id: 4, name: "D"),
  ];
  final _items = fontList.map((animal) => MultiSelectItem<Font>(animal, animal.name)).toList();
  late List<Font?> selectedFonts;
  final _multiSelectKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();
`

Comment: And folllowing is the initstate.

`
void initState() {
    selectedFonts = [
      Font(id: 2, name: "B"),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }
`

Comment: Ok you are trying to set some item selected while opening the  sheet?

Comment: I want to show chips of items that are already present in selectedFonts list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can directly assign `initialValue`, test this widget

```dart
class MulTiSlt extends StatefulWidget {
  const MulTiSlt({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MulTiSlt> createState() => _MulTiSltState();
}

class _MulTiSltState extends State<MulTiSlt> {
  Gender? selected;

  static List<Font> fontList = [
    Font(id: 1, name: "A"),
    Font(id: 2, name: "B"),
    Font(id: 3, name: "C"),
    Font(id: 4, name: "D"),
  ];

  final _multiSelectKey = GlobalKey<FormFieldState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiSelectBottomSheetField<Font?>(
      key: _multiSelectKey,
      initialChildSize: 0.7,
      maxChildSize: 0.8,
      initialValue: [
        fontList[1],
        // here include initial values 
      ],
      listType: MultiSelectListType.CHIP,
      items: fontList
          .map(
            (animal) => MultiSelectItem(
              animal,
              animal.name,
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
      onConfirm: (values) {},
    );
  }
}
class Font {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  Font({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });
}
```